# Find the limit of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_0$ be a real number such that $|a_0|< 1$ and $a_n = \sqrt\frac{1+a_{n-1} }{2}$ for $n \ge1.$ Let $b_n=4^n(1-a_n).$

Then $lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ is equal to

(A) $(cos^{-1}a_0)^2$

(B)  $\frac{(cos^{-1}a_0)^2}{2}$

(C) $cos^{-1}a_0$

(D) $\frac{(cos^{-1}a_0)}{2}$

Note: I already gave enough time to solve this problem but got no conclusion till now. And it can be easily deduced that $a_n \to1$ and $b_n$ is of $\frac{0}{0}$ form.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is B. You can try checking it numerically.

Start with $a_0=1-\delta$, where $\delta$ is small. Then $a_1=\sqrt(\frac{2-\delta}{2})=1-\delta/4$ to first order. We can see that $\delta$ is divided by 4 each time, so $a_n=1-\frac{\delta}{4^n}$ to first order.

By inserting our $a_n$ into the equation for $b_n$, we can see that $b_n=\delta$ to first order. Then you have to find the Taylor expansion of $cos^{-1}(1-x)$. $cos^{-1}(1-\delta)=\sqrt{2\delta}$ to first order, so B must be correct.